# Restrict post dates into Full Calendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I´m developing Full Calendar like [this](http://keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/admin_1/app_calendar.html), but instead of creating events I just get it from the database.

So now I developing Backend to receive days of the week of an event like this:[image: ![enter image description here]

As you can see I receive booleans within days of the week

Now I want to restrict if one of this days come false, calendar doesn´t allow me to do that

JS Function:

```
function isGreaterThanToday(date) {
    return date < hoy ? false : true;
}

function updateAssignedEvent(event, delta, revertFunc) {

    if (!isGreaterThanToday(event.start)) {
        mostrarError("Cant post an event today or before today.");
        revertFunc();
        return;
    }

    event.start = $.fullCalendar.moment(moment($.fullCalendar.moment(event.start.format())._i));

    event.end = event.end ? $.fullCalendar.moment(moment($.fullCalendar.moment(event.end.format())._i)) : event.start;

    event.color = getTareaCalendarioColor(event.tipoResponsable,
      event.estatusTarea,
      event.start,
      event.end.diff(event.start, 'hours') <= 24 ? event.start : event.end);

    updateEvent(event).then(function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
            revertFunc();
            return;
        }
        event.end = event.end !== event.start ? event.end.add(1, 'day') : event.end;
        $calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    }, function(error) {
        revertFunc();
    });
}
```

As you can see I have a function called`function isGreaterThanToday(date)`, I use it to restrict post an event today or before today. I want to do something like this, but I don´t have an idea of how can I call these booleans and compare for example Sunday of the calendar with Sunday of boolean receive. Can anyone help me there? Regards

For example into my function I add:

```
if (event.accion.agendarDomingo != true) {
    mostrarError("Sunday is not allowed");
    revertFunc();
    return;
}
```

But how can I compare with my `event.start` and `event.end` DAY?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get day of week using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) use 'e' as a format. result will be 0..6 Monday to Sunday.

```
event.start.format('e');
```

To check if the time is passed use [isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) function:

> If nothing is passed to moment#isAfter, it will default to the current time.

`moment(event.start).isAfter();`

Now these two validation constraints combined would look like this:

```
function isDateValid(date) {
    return date.format('e') !== "6" && moment(date).isAfter();
}
```